# Pointers Basic : A simple query

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to cpp and learning pointers. while practicing the codes i came across this. When i do &(a pointer), it gives an another memory location.i want to know what this address is. I assume its the location where the ptr is saved. it has to be saved somewhere though it has the memory of value variable.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int v =6;
  int *ptr;

  ptr = &v;

  cout << "1: " << ptr << endl;

  cout << "2: " << *ptr << endl;

  cout << "3: " << &ptr << endl;

  return 0;

}
```

OUTPUT:
1: 0x29cc6c

2: 6

3: 0x29cc68

Comment: A pointer is a variable as anything else, a variable has it's unique address, that can be obtained with the `&` operator. So nothing weird happens in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.

Output 1 is the value of the pointer, which is the address that it points to.

Output 2 is the "dereferenced" pointer which means it is the value contained at Output 1 (the location the pointer is pointing to).

Output 3 is the location where the pointer (which contains the value from output 1) is being stored.

Answer (score 2):

You got it perfectly right:

- `v` is a variable, so `&v` is the adress where `v` is stored in memory;
- `ptr` is a variable as well, so `&ptr` is the adress where `ptr` is stored in memory.

In your example, because these variables are stored one after the other (on the local *stack*), their adresses are only 4 bytes apart.